# ns-3 Build Error

Tags: python, build, waf, ns-3

I am trying to build ns-3 using the command `./waf` inside the ns-3 folder,

but it gives me this:

```
        Waf: Entering directory `/home/mptcp/build'
        Waf: Leaving directory `/home/mptcp/build'
        source not found: 'model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc' in 

bld(features=['cxx', 'cxxshlib', 'ns3module'], 

ns3_dir_location='src/applications', pcfilegen=bld(features='ns3pcfile', 

idx=2, meths=[], prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), _name='', source='', 

module='ns3-applications', mappings={}, path=/home/mptcp/src/applications, 

target='') in /home/mptcp/src/applications, use=['ns3-internet', 'ns3-

config-store', 'ns3-stats', 'ns3-mptcp'], mappings={}, uselib='', meths=

['_add_test_code', 'apply_bundle', 'process_rule', 'process_source', 

'apply_link', 'apply_implib', 'process_use', 'propagate_uselib_vars', 

'apply_incpaths', 'apply_vnum', 'set_macosx_deployment_target'], 

prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), source=['model/bulk-send-

application.cc', 'model/onoff-application.cc', 'model/packet-sink.cc', 

'model/ping6.cc', 'model/radvd.cc', 'model/radvd-interface.cc', 

'model/radvd-prefix.cc', 'model/udp-client.cc', 'model/udp-server.cc', 

'model/seq-ts-header.cc', 'model/udp-trace-client.cc', 'model/packet-loss-

counter.cc', 'model/udp-echo-client.cc', 'model/udp-echo-server.cc', 

'model/v4ping.cc', 'model/application-packet-probe.cc', 'helper/bulk-send-

helper.cc', 'helper/on-off-helper.cc', 'helper/packet-sink-helper.cc', 

'helper/ping6-helper.cc', 'helper/udp-client-server-helper.cc', 

'helper/udp-echo-helper.cc', 'helper/v4ping-helper.cc', 'helper/radvd-

helper.cc', 'model/mp-tcp-packet-sink.cc', 'model/mp-tcp-bulk-send-

application.cc', 'model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc', 'helper/mp-tcp-

packet-sink-helper.cc', 'helper/mp-tcp-bulk-send-helper.cc'], test=False, 

is_ns3_module=True, install_path='${LIBDIR}', module_deps=['internet', 

'config-store', 'stats', 'mptcp'], dependencies=['internet', 'config-

store', 'stats', 'mptcp'], path=/home/mptcp/src/applications, vnum=None, 

posted=True, is_static=False, target='../../ns3.19-applications-debug', 

idx=1, _name='ns3-applications') in /home/mptcp/src/applications
```

I cant figure out what to do.

**I have removed the file /mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc from the folder and have also edited the wscript file.**

How to remove this error ? This seems to be a missing source file error, what does the error message say ? I have already removed the file references.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a plz see the edit. How to remove this error ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't actually see any Error declaration? Have you got any?

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a this the build error message. I cant do ./waf --run myprog

Comment: As far as I understand the Error, the program leaves the directory and wants to access to a file or directory in the left dirctory, It won't find the given path, so it returns a build error. Since it's a very long error, this has not got to be right! and I'm not sure if I understood the error

Answer (score 0):

The error says that waf can't find `model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc`. In the error message the source attribute of the task generator lists `model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc` as a source. waf is perfectly right :)

If you have removed `model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc` from disk you should ensure that your `wscript` does not consider model/mp-tcp-onoff-application.cc as a source. Without the wscript I can't help you more.

If the wscript build the source list, try to `waf clean` before your build